# Can I create a partition in table based on column value in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, partitioning

I'm working on a table in SQL Server that has let's say three columns:

```
employeeid (PK) | customer id | employee name.
```

I need employee id based on employee name and customer id. Let's say, my table has 100000 records and just 5 customers. So, if I have partition based on Customer ID my retrieval process would be faster I believe. Again, it is not fixed that there will always be these 5 customers, it may increase or decrease, but they will always be finite and limited (let's say won't exceed 20). Is it possible to have partition in my table based on customer id? Or is there any other way to improve or fasten lookup process?

Comment: What types of queries you want to optimize? Getting all rows for particular customer?

Comment: My query would be to get employee id based on employee name and customer id. It could be one record or more. But I believe it will not exceed 10 records. In 80% cases, it would be single record. e.g. select employee_id from table where customer_id=111 and employee_name='xyz'

Comment: So, it will be `SELECT MAX([customer id]) FROM ... WHERE [employee name] = 'Hardik'?`

Comment: It will be select employee_id from table where customer_id=111 and employee_name='Hardik'. It is more like reverse lookup.

Comment: Is it possible an employee_id to have different employee_name for different rows? I think it must be same, right?

Comment: nopes.. one employee id will have single name. However, one name can be of multiple employees. Hence, there could be 2-3 employees with the name 'Hardik'. I'm trying clustered index on customer_id and employee_name.

Comment: OK. Can we create a separate table, called `Employees`  and stored there the unique pairs of `employee ` id and name? This will reduce the table size and normalized your data.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I couldn't test it properly, but yeah indexing only might able to improve the performance.

Answer (score 2):

First, [partitioning is not a performance feature](https://littlekendra.com/2016/05/03/why-table-partitioning-doesnt-speed-up-query-performance-video/). Yes, you can partition your table, but it is too small (with 100'000 records doesn't worth it) and partitioning needs clear boundaries. Let's say your customer IDs are 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. Then next customer (#6) comes in and it will reside in the same partition as customer #5. What you actually need is [non-clustered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-2017) on CustomerID, and probably with Employee Name as included column.

Comment: A unique clustered index on CustomerID and EmployeeID could also be appropriate depending on the queries. Like partitioning, only the rows for a given customer will be touched as long as CustomerID is specified in WHERE/JOIN clauses.